# how to get the required output?

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SELECT statement that returns these columns from the Vendors table:

- The vendor_name column
- The vendor_name column in all capital letters
- The vendor_phone column
- The last four digits of each phone number

When you get that working right, add the columns that follow to the result set. This is more difficult because these columns require the use of functions within functions.

- The second word in each vendor name if there is one; otherwise, blanks
- The vendor_phone column with the parts of the number separated by dots as in 555.555.5555

this is what i have tried so far:

```
select vendor_name, UPPER(vendor_name) AS VENDOR_NAME_UPPER,
vendor_phone, SUBSTR(vendor_phone, 11, 4), 
Replace
(replace
(replace(vendor_phone, ') ', '.')
, '(', '')
, '-','.') AS vendor_phone_dot,
SUBSTR(vendor_name, (INSTR(vendor_name, ' ') + 1)) AS Second_Word
from vendors;
```

Comment: Why don't you manipulate this things in program rather than making query complex.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. To expect good answers to your question, you need to try to make it easy for us to understand what is the problem you face, when trying some code. Have you done any research about what you posted? What is your DB structure? What have you tried so far, assuming you have tried anything at all? What didn't work?

Comment: i have reformatted the question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT vendor_name,
UPPER(vendor_name),
vendor_phone,
RIGHT(vendor_phone, 4),
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT(vendor_phone, 13),')','.')," ",""),"-","."),
CASE vendor_name
    WHEN (LOCATE(' ', vendor_name) = 0) THEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(vendor_name, LOCATE(' ', vendor_name) + 1),' ', 1))
    ELSE ''
END
FROM ap.vendors;
```

Murach's MySQL (3rd Edition), Chapter 9, Exercise 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT vendor_name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), UPPER(vendor_name)),SUBSTRING(vendor_phone,  LEN(vendor_phone)-3 ,4) FROM Vendors
```